# Restore windows 7 without "system repair disk"

Tags: windows-7, windows, recovery-disk

I have a blank hard drive. I also have a Windows 7 system image backed up on an external hard drive. I don't have a system repair disk **(SRD)** and also don't have Windows 7 disk. I only have the recovery disks that came with my laptop. There is no option in the recovery disk to restore from a system image. So, I am forced to use the old stuff in the recovery disk.

I have few questions:

1. Can I restore my system from an image on a USB based HDD, without
   any **SRD**?
2. Can I create an SRD in a windows 8 system for a windows 7 system? I
   know this might sound strange, but what if an SRD is just a
   collection of backup utilities?
3. If no microsoft based answer is there, then is there any commercial
   software which can do this instead?

I don't even have access to an original Windows 7 disk right now. So, that option is ruled out too.

Comment: Access to a windows 7 disk is easily solved. (Well, you would need to burn the iso somewhere). See http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft  After that you could create a SRD. A bit the long way around and maybe someone has a better idea.

Comment: @Hennes - The answer suggests downloads from digital river. That is not a microsoft service. So, I'd rather not download from there. Any other options ?

Comment: I understand that they are a legal Microsoft reseller and that their ISOs are clean. I would not link to a site I suspected. Seeing someone pay attention to safety is a good thing though.

Comment: @Hennes - Okay, is it possible to restore using my backup image and by burning the Win 7 ISO onto a DVD ? I guess the dvd will ask me if i want to restore from a hdd, right ? If not, then I am stuck.

Comment: @Hennes - I saw sathya's answer in the same post. His files are exe's and are much smaller than the 3gb iso's. He does not mention what those exes do. But he does point to a link which has some help - http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-create-and-make-bootable-windows-7-iso-from-exe-plus-setup1-box-and-setup2-box-files/

Its hard to understand what is being done in that link.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

you can download a legal, full windows 7 disc of whatever type you please from [here](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/14709-Windows-7-Digital-River-direct-links-Multiple-Languages-X86-amp-X64/page72)

Burn to Disc and boot from there.

Note: These are legal .iso images. You should only access the images that you legitimately own. Doing otherwise for longer than the trail period is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a system  repair disk, from control panel, using your computer or any other computer running windows 7.

I created mine, using the laptop of my brother in order to fix my pc. [here's how](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/create-a-system-repair-disc), this does not answer your question, *"Restore windows 7 without “system repair disk”* but hey if you have a PC, you can do it, that's what I'm saying

Comment: sorry, but i mentioned that this is not possible now.

Comment: @Deen you don't have access to any pc? a friend's pc?

Comment: No. There is one pc but it has windows 7 pro 32 bit. Worse, its loaded with malware :(

Comment: @Deen malware is not a problem, we can fix it if you want, anyway I'll keep searching, i could upload an ISO for you, copying the iso that i use but my computer is 64 bit, so it won't work, I don't think that malware would affect a recovery disk, not sure though, but i don't think so

Comment: thanks, but i am now downloading an iso provided by digital river, a partner of ms. would i need a license key if i want to use this iso (burned onto a dvd) to backup from a system image ?

Comment: @Deen I think so, since all the disks I found were not free, no details on the site? by the way i think you can find free torrents

Comment: come on you can't be serious. torrents are highly likely to have backdoors or malware, exactly the reason why i need to restore my system now.

Comment: @Deen, i know but you asked for free stuff, i tell you about free stuff, want paid stuff i can give you paid stuff :)

Comment: You do not usually need a license key for ms operating systems within 30 days. That should be plenty time to create a recovery disk, or recover a backup (and use the recovered backup with your legal key from that point). I am nt sure how 100% law nitpicking will look at it, but it certainly is within the spirit of the law.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a linux distro called "Clonezilla" as long as the image you created is in a format that it can recognize then you shouldn't have too much problems doing so. It is pretty easy to use and figure out. if you find yourself going "huh???"er reading the options reread them slower and it will make sense (it did for me)